# Como fazer uma geração de textos sem scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

estou tentando gerar textos como ali no text("500g de aveia") mas porem quero gerar sem aquele scroll. Existe algum widget que possa fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class BoxIngredientes extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 100,
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                itemCount: 3,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 5,
                      bottom: 5,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.supervised_user_circle, // trocar esse icon depois
                          size: 22,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 10,
                          ),
                          child: Text("500g de aveia"), 
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode experimentar usar o [`NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html) no `ListView.builder()`:

```
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

Conforme documentação (tradução livre):

> Cria uma física de rolagem que não permite que o usuário faça a rolagem.

Comment: não era bem isso que eu estava pensando, porque precisa colocar fixa, o que preciso precisa ter uma altura dinâmica porque não sei quantos itens vai aparecer

Comment: @WilliamGravina se você usar o `shrinkWrap: true` em conjunto, satisfaz o seu caso de uso?

Comment: obrigado de coração <3